# Published posts are not query-able and not displayed in admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I have encountered this problem many times. This problem only happen when I programmatically create/edit posts. They could be customs post or even Wordpress' default post. The symptoms could be:

- The posts are not visible in admin dashboard. Post count of that custom post type still increase but no post is displayed in the list.
- Created posts are not query-able, even when `post_status` is set to `'any'`. Curiously when I set `post_status` to `published` it works.

**This is a self-answered question**. I encountered this problem several times before and always forget its cause. And searches hint to possibilities that many others are stuck without solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;**: It's `publish`, not `published`.

The cause of this problem is because I when programmatically create new posts, I set its `post_status` to `published`. Common reason for the confusion is when you approve a post programmatically, switching post status from `pending` to `published` because it seem logical.

The reason those posts are showing in neither queries nor admin dashboard is because `WP_Query`'s `post_status => 'any'` doesn't actually query for *'any'* post status as we expect, but *any registered post status*. Since wordpress had no prior knowledge of the post status `published`, they're simply ignored by the queries.

Now here's to hope I don't forget what I wrote today again next year.